# Dictionary Values as distinct Keys

Tags: c#, string, list, dictionary

I have this:

```
        var color = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        color.Add("Blue", new List<string>() { "1", "2" });
        color.Add("Green", new List<string>() { "2", "3" });
        color.Add("Red", new List<string>() { "1", "3" });
        color.Add("Black", new List<string>() { "3" });
        color.Add("Yellow", new List<string>() { "1" });
```

I would to convert this to a

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>>
```

that looks like this:

```
Key: 1, Value: Blue, Red, Yellow
Key: 2, Value: Blue, Green
Key: 3, Value: Green, Red, Black
```

Tried:

```
var test = color.GroupBy(x => x.Value.FirstOrDefault())
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(x => x.Key).ToList());
```

However this only works for one item so ("FirstOrDefault()"), i only get

```
Key: 1, Value: Blue, Red, Yellow
```

How could i do this?
I could loop through the values (distinct) and there loop through the keys and check if value exist then build up a new one but i would like to avoid this and use lamda.

Seen many example of this but with no list of string as values but only a string.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var test = color
    .SelectMany(x => x.Value.Select(v =>
    new
    {
       Color = x.Key,
       Integer = v
    }))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Integer)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(y => y.Color).ToList());
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, I had the same idea as @SamIAm and @kanders84152. I just want to make a little improvement and to add an explanation:

```
var test = color
    .SelectMany(c => c.Value.Select(v => new { Number = v, Color = c.Key }))
    .GroupBy(a => a.Number, a => a.Color)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

The main difference of my solution is that the `GroupBy` part extracts the color from the anonymous type instead of the `ToDictionary` part.

First the `.SelectMany(c => c.Value.Select(v => new { Number = v, Color = c.Key }))` part flattens the nested lists to an enumeration of an anonymous type with numbers and color names.

The original dictionary entries

```
"Blue", { "1", "2" }
"Green", { "2", "3" }
"Red", { "1", "3" }
"Black", { "3" }
"Yellow", { "1" }
```

become

```
{ Number: "1", Color: "Blue" }
{ Number: "2", Color: "Blue" }
{ Number: "2", Color: "Green" }
{ Number: "3", Color: "Green" }
{ Number: "1", Color: "Red" }
{ Number: "3", Color: "Red" }
{ Number: "3", Color: "Black" }
{ Number: "1", Color: "Yellow" }
```

`.GroupBy(a => a.Number, a => a.Color)` then re-groups these values by the number and takes the color as value

```
"1", { "Blue", "Red", "Yellow" }
"2", { "Blue", "Green" }
"3", { "Green" "Red", "Black" }
```

This is almost the desired result, except that we have an `IGrouping<string, string>` (where the groups represent a key and an enumeration of values)
 instead of a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`. Finally `.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList())` creates the desired dictionary with the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd flatten it first

```
var colorflat = color
    .SelectMany(c => c.Value.Select(n => new {Color=c.Key, Number=n}));
```

and then I'd group to the new format

```
var test = colorflat
    .GroupBy(c => c.Number)
    .ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Select(x => x.Color).ToList());
```